# Oxygen production from thermal decomposition of metal oxides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Does thermal decomposition of metal oxides always produce oxygen?

Answer (score 4):

A lot of metal oxides decompose under liberation of $\ce{O2}$ when subjected to sufficiently high temperatures. For example, [$\ce{HgO}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury(II)_oxide) decomposes at temperatures above $\pu{500^\circ C}$ into elemental mercury and oxygen:

$$\ce{2HgO ->~ 2Hg + O2}$$

However, disproportionation is another possible reaction pathway. An example is the thermal decomposition of iron(II) oxide to elemental iron and iron(II, III) oxide at temperatures below $\pu{575^\circ C}$ ($\ce{FeO}$ is more stable above that temperature; sources: [1](http://books.google.de/books?id=i9nyvTYBQtAC&pg=PA305&lpg=PA305&dq=thermal%20decomposition%20of%20metal%20oxides%20%2B%20disproportion&source=bl&ots=Dr9JNqyiXN&sig=FXfQ2mF_zhLgraSXF27OscDZMYs&hl=de&sa=X&ei=b_0BVKPAMMiB4gTUsoDYBw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=thermal%20decomposition%20of%20metal%20oxides%20%2B%20disproportion&f=false), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(II)_oxide)):

$$\ce{4FeO \rightleftharpoons Fe + Fe3O4}$$

Another example is the decompostion of $\ce{SnO}$ at temperatures between $700\mathrm -\pu{1000K}$, which proceeds via an intermediate $\ce{Sn3O4}$ mixed oxide. Tin disproportionates from the oxidation state +II in $\ce{SnO}$ to $0$ in $\ce{Sn}$ and +IV in $\ce{SnO2}$ ([1](http://books.google.de/books?id=i9nyvTYBQtAC&pg=PA305&lpg=PA305&dq=thermal%20decomposition%20of%20metal%20oxides%20%2B%20disproportion&source=bl&ots=Dr9JNqyiXN&sig=FXfQ2mF_zhLgraSXF27OscDZMYs&hl=de&sa=X&ei=b_0BVKPAMMiB4gTUsoDYBw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=thermal%20decomposition%20of%20metal%20oxides%20%2B%20disproportion&f=false), [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin(II)_oxide)).

\begin{aligned}
\ce{4SnO ->~& Sn3O4 + Sn} \\
\ce{Sn3O4 ->~& 2SnO2 + Sn}
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the examples given by Jannis Andreska, metal peroxides, such as barium peroxide and lithium peroxide also release oxygen upon heating:

$$
\ce{2 BaO2 ->[\text{T = 700 °C}] 2 BaO + O2} \\
\ce{2 Li2O2 ->[\text{T = 195 °C}] 2 Li2O + O2}
$$

This was once used to produce pure oxygen.

On the other hand, some, if not most, metal oxides are extremely heat resistant. For example, once sintered at temperatures between $1700$ and $\pu{2000°C}$, magnesium oxide $(\ce{MgO})$ can be heated up to its melting point ($\sim\pu{2800°C}$) without decomposition and can thus be used as a lining for heat sensors.